# Certificate error: Mismatched address for self hosted website

Tags: c#, https, ssl-certificate, owin, self-hosting

When opening my self hosted website i get a certificate error: mismatched address.

right now i set up my host like this in the code:

```
host = "https://*:" + PortNumber
```

And i used the following command to add the certificate

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=247951f42efcc102cddef79e9f4b2e8830f9b2d0 appid={12346978-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf}
```

I have tried this with two different certificates. One was called (friendly name) TestCertificate the other localhost. 
I added both to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities butt both gave the same issue.

How do i resolve this certificate error?

Comment: Try localhost (or actual IP or host name) instead of 0.0.0.0.

Comment: The Url you are connecting to in your browser to open your webpage must be the same as the one in your certificate. Look for field 'Subject Alternative Name' in the certificate. Here you should have something like 'DNS Name=mystite.com' or 'DNS Name=127.0.0.1'. If these do not match with your URL in the browser. You will get the error described.